# Ubuntu core: snap core repeatedly mount and umount

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core

When I boot up Ubuntu core OS on my board with arm64, snap core repeatedly mount and umount like below, I have no idea why it happens.

```
         Mounting Mount unit for core, revision 4915...
[  OK  ] Mounted Mount unit for core, revision 4915.
[  OK  ] Unmounted Mount unit for core, revision 4915.
         Mounting Mount unit for core, revision 4915...
[  OK  ] Mounted Mount unit for core, revision 4915.
[  OK  ] Unmounted Mount unit for core, revision 4915.
         Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
[  OK  ] Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
         Mounting Mount unit for core, revision 4915.
```